# Why am I getting the error 'GetXDocument()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, html-agility-pack

I have the following class file which will search a page and extract certain information and display it as an output:

```
public class Crawler
{

    public string Url
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Crawler() { }
    public Crawler(string Url)
    {
        this.Url = Url;
    }
    public XDocument GetXDocument()
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb doc1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        doc1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (conpatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc2 = doc1.Load(Url);
        doc2.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
        doc2.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
        doc2.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        GetXDocument xdoc = GetXDocument.Parse(doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html").OuterHtml);
        return xdoc;
    }
}
```

When I run the web application, I get the following error:

`Error  1   'WebApplication1.Crawler.GetXDocument()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'    c:\users\usrs\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Crawler.cs  30  13  WebApplication1`

`Error  2   'WebApplication1.Crawler.GetXDocument()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context c:\users\usrs\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Crawler.cs  30  33  WebApplication1`

I am trying to use the following web page example: [Link to WebCrawler](http://wantbjaccp.blogspot.com/2011/04/create-sample-web-crawler-auto-content.html?showComment=1401800076574#c5622736736907286255)

My web application solution looks like this:

[image]

Can someone also please tell me where do I add the `main` function.

Comment: `GetXDocument()` is a method: `public XDocument GetXDocument()`. So you cannot use it as if it were a type: `GetXDocument doc = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
GetXDocument xdoc = GetXDocument.Parse(doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html").OuterHtml);
```

to

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html").OuterHtml);
```

`GetXDocument` is a method and it return an object which is a `XDocument`

Comment: Thank you for the reply... but that's not working for me :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge is it the same error?

Comment: I have to also change the second GetXDocument to XDocument and it worked! Thank you. I UPVOTED... Not sure why someone downvoted your answer.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Awesome, fixed this side as well. Glad we could get it sorted :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge if you are happy with the answer please accept it so that the issue can be closed

Answer (score 1):

Change `GetXDocument` to `XDocument` in your function:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(...
```

> where do I add the main function?

Web apps don't have a `main` function.  they respond to HTTP requests through handlers.

Comment: Should I add a Default.ASPX page and put the function there?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I don't know - you don't provide enough context.  do you want the class to be used when a page is requested?  Or run periodically?  Or as part of a larger application?

Comment: I think I will create a Windows Form because I want it to be visible at all times and not part of a page.